# Django REST Framework: require login to view API

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am working through this series on the Django REST Framework and have a few videos left: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEsfXFp6DpzTOcOVdZF-th7BS_GYGguAS

Unless I missed it somehow, I haven't seen anything on how to require login to view the API. I Googled such things as "Django REST require login", but didn't see anything other than creating authorization in general using Django REST API. I imagine there is a way to do it and would like to implement it because having a wide open API wouldn't work for my project.

Can someone point me in the right direction for setting login required for the API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got the answer in video 31. In project settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
}
```

Comment: This  does not work; I can still  see the API when logged out (Django REST version 2.3).

To be clear, you also need to add:

   permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)